# a table with cell \pm another cell using pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

Say, i have a text file

```
10.0123235 5.0234324
11.2342345 6.02343256
```

where the first column is value and the second is a standard deviation.

I am trying to figure out how to automatically put it into a table with `\pm` sign using pgfplotstable? 
So what i want to be in table is `$10\pm5$` and `$11\pm6$`.

Should be something in style like

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={0},
    columns/0/.style={
         column name={$value$},
         postproc cell content/.style={
              @cell content=##0$\pm$##1
         }
    }
   ]...
```

but it does not work...

**UPDATE**:
here is a minimal LaTeX example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={0},
    columns/0/.style={
         column name={$0$},
         postproc cell content/.append style={
           /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{$\pm$ ##2 }
        }
    }
]{
10.0123235 & 5.0234324 \\
11.2342345 & 6.02343256
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE2**:

almost working example, the question is : how to control precision in numbers?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
10.0123235  5.0234324 
11.2342345  6.02343256
}\loadedtable

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
   create col/assign/.code={%
         \getthisrow{0}\entry
         \getthisrow{1}\dev
         \edef\entry{\entry$\pm$\dev}%
         \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
   }]
  {new}\loadedtable

\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={new},
    columns/new/.style={
         string type,
         column name={$new$},
    }
]\loadedtable
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE3:
I found a nice topic on printing complex [numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136331/formatting-an-array-of-complex-numbers-with-pgfplotstable). It is actually very similar to what i want to achieve... Trying to bend their result to my needs...

Comment: Could you please provide a fully compilable example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))? It would help the solvers a lot!

Comment: @Malipivo hi. I updated the question with minimal example.

Comment: Does this help http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123075/3235?

Comment: @percusse it does, but it does not have rounding. I think to round up numbers one need all those tricks with toks0/toks1. btw, that's exactly what i did in Update2!..

Comment: You can just use pretty printing of numbers instead of `toks` such as `\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=5]{...}` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality can also be achieved with [the `collcell` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell):

[image]

Below, I defined two column types, `V` for the numerical value column and `E` for error.  The `V` column stores the integer result in `\Value` and this gets printed with the error in the `E` column.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\Value}{}%
\newcommand*{\Error}{}%

\newcommand{\SetValue}[1]{\pgfmathparse{int(floor(#1))}\xdef\Value{\pgfmathresult}}
\newcommand{\DisplayValueAndError}[1]{\pgfmathparse{int(floor(#1))}$\Value \pm \pgfmathresult$}

\newcolumntype{V}{>{\collectcell\SetValue}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\DisplayValueAndError}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{V E}
    10.0123235  & 5.0234324  \\
    11.2342345  & 6.02343256 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\def\pgfmathprintpmnumber#1#2{%
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\thisrow{#1}}%
    \let\valueRe=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\thisrow{#2}}%
    \let\valueIm=\pgfmathresult
    \edef\valueRe{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill]{\valueRe}}%
    %\show\valueRe
    \edef\valueIm{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill]{\valueIm}}%
    %\show\valueIm
    \toks0=\expandafter{\valueRe}%
    \toks1=\expandafter{\valueIm}%
    % we cannot use \edef\value{\valueRe\valueIm} as this would
    % expand \pgfmathprintnumber - which is not expandable.
    % Writing \the<tokenregister> expands the content of
    % <tokenregister> exactly once:
    \edef\value{\the\toks0 & $\pm$\the\toks1 }%
}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
10.0123235  5.0234324 
11.2342345  6.02343256
}\loadedtable

\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/C11/.style={string type, column type={r@{}l}, column name={$c11$}},
  create on use/C11/.style={%
    create col/assign/.code={%
       \pgfmathprintpmnumber{0}{1}
       \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\value
    }
  },
  columns={C11}
  ]{\loadedtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which is a light modification of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136331/formatting-an-array-of-complex-numbers-with-pgfplotstable).